# How to use PHP if conditions to act according to the input of a search bar in HTML

Tags: php, html

So I've got a code for a search bar in HTML where specific fruit names are passed onto the PHP page, where it echoes a certain message in reply...

Here's the HTML code -

```
    <form action="pass.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="find" name="search"/>
<button  type="submit" 
onclick="javascript: if(document.getElementById('find').value!='Banana' && document.getElementById('find').value!='Apple') 
{alert('Fruit not found');return false;}">&nbsp</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the PHP code...

```
if ($_POST['id'] = "Banana") {
    echo "This is a Banana";
}

    else {
    echo "This is not a Banana"  
}
```

The output just gives me "This is a Banana" regardless of my input. I know my code is wrong, I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $_POST variable has the wrong key value, it should be:

```
  if ($_POST['search'] == "Banana") {
    echo "This is a Banana";
  }else {
    echo "This is not a Banana"  
  }
```

and your comparison operator was wrong according to @lluisrojass.

Comment: Now even when I enter "Banana" in the search bar, it gives me this output: Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shazaib\petshop\redirect.php on line 3
This is not a Banana

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `==` or `===`. for strings it's recommended to use binary safe `strcmp`function to check for equality.

Comment: Using == gives me this error Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shazaib\petshop\redirect.php on line 4

where line 4 is - 

if ($_POST['id'] == "Banana") {